# Start activity by clicking on widget

Tags: android, android-activity, click, widget

I newbie at programming Android and I try to do a widget which has be able get some data from ISP about my account. There are a lot of unknown things how to do it, but I have did a few things - I've got a widget with configure activity, where user should  type login and password. Widget stores the data in SharedPerferences, and when it's time to update widget I use a Service to start an AsyncTask to getting it from ISP an account data. Now I want to do start an activity by click on widget. I've tried all advice which I found on this site and widget can't start activity. My widget based on another widget which placed here https://github.com/Arturus/MetrikaWidget. I dont understand what and where I should change to start activity by clicking on my widget. Thanks.

UPDATE:
My update function, where I suggest I should place PendingIntent

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate");

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)
    {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }

    /* An updateAppWidget functions looks like as:

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
    context.startService(intent);
    */

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailedStatActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout, pendingIntent);

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), WidgetProvider.class.getName());

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, views);
}
```

Comment: How you are trying to start the activity now ? Paste code which you are doing now

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use this snippet in `onUpdate()` method of your widget `AppWidgetProvider` class:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widgetlayout);
    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);

    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, configPendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
}
```

Here `widgetlayout` is name of your widget layout and `R.id.widget` is it's parent layout id.

**Edit**:
Now,I see your code that you added to your question.You would to do:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);
```

(that start's activity) instead of

```
PendingIntent.getService(...);
```

that attempt to starts service.Good luck.

References:
[doityourselfandroid.com](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/05/24/developing-android-home-screenwidgets/)

[helloandroid.com](http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, it's works, I placed this 5 srings inside loop in onUpdate and click on widget works!

Comment: is it really going to open two activities? i only see one activity in the intent so how two activity will open parallely

Comment: @silverFoxA It does not do that.Only opens one Activity.

Answer (score 10):

```
Intent inet = new Intent(your_action);
inet.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pIntentNetworkInfo = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2, 
            inet, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(you_component_when_the_user_pressing_this_activity_should_start, pIntentNetworkInfo);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about "Creating widget from another widget". This is out of my knowledge but I suggest you to build your own widget.

Apart from that, calling activity from widget should be using [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)

Here is simple example to do it

```
Intent iSetting = new Intent(this, MyConfig.class);
PendingIntent piSetting = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, iSetting, 0);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.IdComponent, piSetting);
```

Or you might need to see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937236/launching-activity-from-widget) and [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: My bad. I mean based on another widget instead created. I suggest I should place this code in my update function? But my update function already using to start a Service - it would be work? I already have tried change update function, but it's no works.

Comment: Yes onUpdate method usually just start the Service. Inside the Service class itself, you could put those codes on onStart.

Comment: Just replace `this` with `context`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initiate the launcher activity, I have integrated the `addCategory()` and `setAction()` methods into the `onUpdate()` method.

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

configIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
configIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");

PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, Values.REQ_CODE, configIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_widget, configPendingIntent);
```