# How do I start an Activity when Widget is clicked?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an application for example it's name is : `SHOPPING`

I would like to create a widget that will show last products from my web service, then after click on it(imageview or button), must open a class of `SHOPPING` application (To buy product).

is it possible to open a class of `SHOPPING` application from widget ?

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554085/start-activity-by-clicking-on-widget

Comment: I'm confused. to create a widget I must create an another project or I must put it in my application (SHOPPING) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy can put widget in your application.
In your manifest file:

```
<receiver
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:label="Example Widget"
   android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
   <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"      />
   </intent-filter>

   <meta-data
      android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
      android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```